# IOException Network is unreachable

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp

We have code using UDP socket for communication.  In this code, application is sending a packet to a given server (identified by given hostname and port). This code is an extracted out from a large code base.

```
        class Test {
            private static int UDP_PORT_NUMBER=15000;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String host = “192.168.2.10”;
        byte[] bytes = {(byte)0xd1, 0x35, (byte)0x39, (byte)0xea, (byte)0xa2, (byte)0xd8};
        DatagramSocket datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                final InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length,
                        inetAddress, UDP_PORT_NUMBER);
                datagramSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
      }
```

However, I am getting following exception in our case while calling send on datagram socket:

```
java.io.IOException: Network is unreachable
        at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
```

What is the meaning of network unreachable in UDP and how does it get detected for UDP which is connectionless? What are cases where I can get network unreachable IOException in UDP socket?

Comment: Imo _network unreachable_ has nothing to do with UDP or TCP, as it happens on layer 3 of the OSI model. There is simply no route to the requested IP address.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the IP addresses of the machine where you run this are.

Comment: 1st step - Can you ping the address??

Comment: 2nd step - Is the port listening???  use this tool http://ping.eu/

Comment: Machine address is 192.168.2.10. Address can be pinged. But the case is that this exception was observed in the past. Now, it cannot be emulated. Hence, I want to know what is case behind IOException so that we can understand problem better and take action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network unreachable message is an ICMP message. When a host tries to reach another host on a different network, it sends the layer-3 packet to its configured gateway. If the gateway ( or any router in the path) doesn't know how to reach the other network, it will generate an ICMP message and send it back to the host.

Comment: The solution involves networking, not programming. You need to make sure that there is a layer-3 network path from source to destination.